Pullback of the standard basis 1-form in Prof. Ted Shifrin's Multivariable Calculus book and Lectures
Setup: Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be open and $\textbf{g}: U \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be smooth. Let $\omega \in \mathcal{A}^{k}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and then define $\textbf{g}^{*}\omega \in \mathcal{A}^{k}(U)$ as follows. Since my question concerns only scalar fields I will just define that.
Definition: Pullback of $f \in \mathcal{A}^{0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ by $\textbf{g}$ is defined as $\textbf{g}^{*}f = f \circ \textbf{g}$
My question is regarding the pullback of $dx_{i}: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$. Why can't we use the definition above to arrive at the pullback of $dx_{i}$ by $\textbf{g}$, as it is also a scalar function? i.e., $\textbf{g}^{*}dx_{i} = dx_{i} \circ \textbf{g}$ which will give the $i$-th component of the function $\textbf{g}$.
Prof. Shifrin separately defines the pullback of the standard basis 1-forms as:
Let $\textbf{g}(\textbf{u}) = \textbf{x}$ then $\textbf{g}^{*}dx_{i} = dg_{i} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\partial g_{i}}{\partial u_{j}} du_{j}$.
I think this question is closely related to Is $\mathrm{d}x_i$ a 0-form or a 1-form?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

As the answer below asks, what does $dx_i\circ\mathbf g$ even mean? We're supposed to get $dg_i$, which, at a point $\mathbf a\in U\subset\Bbb R^m$, eats a vector $\mathbf v\in\Bbb R^m$ [Note that you have a typo at the very beginning]. You want to get the directional derivative of $g_i$ at $\mathbf a$ in the direction $\mathbf v$. Your attempt at a definition does not at all define a $1$-form on $U$, does it? BTW, you might find my (YouTube) lectures based on this book helpful; they are available at the link on my profile.

Thank you for mentioning the typo, I have edited the post. Yes! I am also watching the videos and reading your book.
What I mean by $dx_{i} \circ \textbf{g}$ is $g_{i}$, the $i$-th component function of $\textbf{g}$ which belongs to $\mathcal{A}^{0}(U)$. By definition of $dx_{i}$, it also turns out to be a $0$-form and therefore, I am able to use the definition that is given in the OP(this definition is from the book).
I don't understand what you mean by "we're supposed to", is the motivation behind defining $\textbf{g}^{*}dx_{i} = dg_{i}$ coming from change of variables formula?

No, $dx_i$ is never a $0$-form. Never.

But by definition of $dx_{i}$, I am unable to tell that it is not a $0$-form(i.e., $dx_{i} \in \mathcal{A}^{0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ or not). I might be missing something subtle to resolve it.

The subtlety is that you are wanting to confuse points in $U$ with vectors in $\Bbb R^n$. A $1$-form assigns to each point of $U$ a (linear) function on vectors.  A $0$-form assigns to each point of $U$ a real number.

Because $\mathbf{g} $ is a function and $dx_i$ is a 1-form, so it is not clear what their composite $dx_i \circ \mathbf{g} $ is supposed to mean.

I don't claim to fully understand your question(s), but let me try to help with the following.

Why can't we ... $\textbf{g}^{*}dx_{i} = dx_{i} \circ \textbf{g}$

...

it is not clear what their composite $dx_i \circ \mathbf{g}$ is supposed to mean

We use 2 facts:

Pullback commutes with exterior derivative: $g^{\ast}d x_i=d(g^{\ast}x_i)$. Notice the brackets.
Pullback of a function (0-form) is just a precomposition: $g^{\ast}x_i = x_i \circ g$

Therefore, $g^*dx_i = d(x_i \circ g)$.
